# Where is my program going out of bounds? I get "Process returned -1073740940 (0xC0000374)" at the end

Tags: arrays, c, overflow

I really can't see an issue, but then again, I just started learning C a few weeks ago, as a way to get faster code than what I was using.My guess is it has to do with my memory allocation. This is small, but eventually I will be using this process with Count values up to 25.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int i;
int j;

int Count = 2;                                                 /* set number of bits */

int Combos = pow(2,Count);                                     /* calculate count of all 6 bit binary numbers */

int SIZE = (Combos + 1) * (Count + 1);                         /* calculate number of array elements */
                                                               /* rows * columns */
                                                               /* rows = Combos + 1 */
                                                               /* columns = count +1 (row number + bits)*/
                                                               /* 0th spot will hold row number */

printf("SIZE = %d\n", SIZE);                                   /* print number of array elements */


int (*a)[Count + 1] = malloc(SIZE);                            /* allocate memory for array based on size of */
                                                               /* int variable times SIZE */
                                                               /* (SIZE) is number of elements */

if (a == NULL)                                                 /* if not enough memory, print error message */
{
      fprintf(stderr,"Could not allocate that much memory");
      return 1;
}

/* do something with array */

    for (i =0; i<= Combos; i++){

        a[i][0] = i;                                           /* set 0th element of this row to row number */

        printf("a[%d][0] = %d ", i,a[i][0]);                   /* print 0th element of this row */

        for (j =1; j<= Count; j++){                            /* print the rest of the elements in this row */

            a[i][j] = 1;

            printf("a[%d][%d] = %d ", i,j,a[i][j]);

                                  }                            /* end j loop */

printf("\n");                                                  /* line feed */

                               }                               /* end i loop */

free(a);                                                       /* release memory allocated for array */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `malloc` needs to know the number of **bytes** in the array, not the number of elements. So you need to `malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int))`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `malloc(K)` allocates `K` bytes of memory.
If you'd like to allocate an array consisting of `N` elements of type `T`, you need to call `malloc(N * sizeof(T))`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    const size_t COUNT = 30;
    const size_t COMBOS = (size_t)1 << COUNT;
    const size_t SIZE = (COMBOS + 1) * (COUNT + 1);
    printf("SIZE = %zu\n", SIZE);
    int (*a)[COUNT + 1] = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int));
    if (a == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate that much memory\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= COMBOS; i++)
    {
        a[i][0] = i;
        printf("a[%d][0] = %d%s", i, a[i][0], " ");
        for (j = 1; j <= COUNT; j++)
        {
            a[i][j] = 1;
            printf("a[%d][%d] = %d%s", i, j, a[i][j], (j == COUNT ? "\n" : " "));
        }
    }
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Staring me right in the face. I missed the sizeof(int) that was needed. Also I like the usage of size_t to keep numbers non-negative, that did not occur to me. I assume that (j == COUNT ? "\n" : " ") only prints a line feed and a space.